# Symfony 1.4 Response Object & Page Title

Tags: php, symfony1

Is there a way to get page title in a layout? I would expect sfResponse::getTitle() to work, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I 'spose that $sf_response->getTitle(); ought to work... were you calling sfResponse::getTitle() statically?

Comment: You're right! $sf_response->getTitle(); worked. I'm dumb, I wasn't aware $sf_response was made available in layouts.

Answer (score 0):

Any reason you're not using the [include_title()](http://www.symfony-project.org/book/1_2/07-Inside-the-View-Layer#chapter_07_sub_page_layout) helper?

Comment: I don't want to include the title tag, just the title. Reason: <h1> tag at the top of the page layout, wanted it to be populated with the page title automatically.